# How to stdout selected value in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, select, user-controls, syntactic-sugar

1. Suposse user hits `SPACE` in a text -field. I want to check the value in the select -box. I use `input.addEventListener('keydown', function(e)...` to track the `SPACE`-hitting-point but how can I get the value of the select block `<select id='topic'><option value="hello"></option> ...</section>`?
2. How can you stdout the value of the selected index? Cannot understand why not below.

   ```
       var el = document.getElementById("topic");
       var topicValue = el.options[el.selectedIndex].value;

       // PROBLEM: Won't do anything (despite inside <script> -tags)
       window.alert(topicValue);
   ```

where the `topic` is the select `<select id="topic"[^>]*>[^<]*</select>`.

Comment: you'll want the `change` event.

Comment: Why do you keep saying `stdout`?  Client-side, JavaScript really only has one way.

Comment: vol7ron: Perhaps, I am stupid. Sorry but won't care about defs, banged my head to this topic too long, googling returns suggestions such as `el.options[el.selectedIndex].value;` but it is mind-eating when they don't work. Trying to solve this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The events work in the select, not to options but just conditional to the script.

```
<html>
<body>

<script>
        function alertMe(option){
                if(option == "saab"){
                        window.alert("you clicked saab in selec!");
                        document.getElementById("txt").value='saab!';
                }
        }
</script>


<select onChange="alertMe(this.value);">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="m"> Mercedes</option>
  <option>Audi</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="txt" value="change me"></input>

</body>
</html>
```

**[Answers to the updated]**

1. You can access the select with `document.getElementById('topic').options.selectedIndex` or `mySelect.options[selectedIndex].value` (does not work with me). And apparently you could create a form to which you could refer by `document.forms['topic'].elements[id]` but not sure about this one. [More.](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/JavaScript/0200__Form/SelectoptionsselectedIndex.htm)
2. @Kosh that is irritating! Just do a `dictionary = {0:"topic", 1:"hello",...,n:"topic_{n}"}` and then use the `getElementById('topic').selectedId` as a key and forget the values. Not solved but rounded.

**[Update]** I think I solved it, just `el.value`, no `selectedIndex` needed:

```
<html>
<body>

<script>

function printSelectValue()
{
        var el = document.getElementById("selectOne");
        alert(el.value);

}
</script>


<select id="selectOne" onChange="printSelectValue()"> 
<option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
<option value="saab">Saab</option>
<option value="m"> Mercedes</option>
</select>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There any many events you can look at.

This has a list of them all
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp

onkeydown and onmousedown will alert you prior to the onchange (user pressing enter) event